# Permission denied while run pytest in Ubuntu

Tags: python, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, docker-image

I have installed the container by `docker-compose up`. Then enter in my image by `docker exec -it connectors_connectors_1 bash`. And run the test `pytest test_all_connector.py` and i got error. I use `Ubuntu`

```
E       AssertionError: Sources in the data are not as expected, [{'cm360': "[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'mediacost_4017119502.csv'"}, {'bing': "[Errno 13] Permission denied: '6012438.zip'"}]
E       assert ['(direct)', ... 'dv360', ...] == ['(direct)', ...'criteo', ...]
E         At index 3 diff: 'criteo' != 'bing'
E         Right contains 2 more items, first extra item: 'snapchat'
E         Use -v to get more diff

test_all_connector.py:344: AssertionError
```

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.10.6@sha256:8d1f943ceaaf3b3ce05df5c0926e7958836b048b700176bf9c56d8f37ac13fca

RUN apt -y update \
  && apt -y upgrade \
  && apt install -y --no-install-recommends git gcc libc6-dev libffi-dev libpq-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev g++ \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
  && useradd -ms /bin/bash connectors \
  && mkdir -p /var/connectors_cache/connectors /var/connectors_cache/flask \
  && chown -R connectors:connectors /var/connectors_cache \
  && pip install --upgrade pip
    
USER connectors
ENV PATH="/home/connectors/.local/bin:${PATH}"

# Install the packages before copying /app so the execution stays cached
COPY --chown=connectors:connectors ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt

RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt

COPY --chown=connectors:connectors . /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN pip install -e .

ENTRYPOINT ["/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

`test_all_connector.py`:

```
"""Tests for the /all connector."""
import datetime
from collections.abc import Mapping
from unittest.mock import MagicMock, patch

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pytest
import requests
import connectors
from connectors.all.connector import Connector as AllConnector
from base.types import UserHandledException
from tests.conftest import field_lists


# many tests here have invalid names which are reasonable
# pylint: disable=invalid-name
# protected members are handled here to build mocks
# pylint: disable=protected-access


class ConnectorThatDoesNothing:
    """Mock connector that returns None as data."""

    # pylint: disable=unused-argument,too-few-public-methods
    def get_data(self, **kwargs):
        """Return None for this mock connector."""
        return None


def test_all_connector_calls_all_non_excluded_connectors():
    """Test that all the connectors are actually called by /all."""

    class AllConnectorCountingConnectors(AllConnector):
        """Mock /all connector that counts the number of connectors called."""

        # pylint: disable=abstract-method
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):  # pylint: disable=unused-argument
            self.conn_called_connectors = set()
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        def _get_single_connector(self, connector_name):
            self.logger.info("Calling _get_single_connector for %s", connector_name)
            self.conn_called_connectors.add(connector_name)
            return ConnectorThatDoesNothing

        def _get_connectors_with_db_config(self):
            # Assume that all the connectors have a config in db
            all_connectors = connectors.__all__.copy()
            self.logger.info("All connectors with db config: %s", all_connectors)
            return all_connectors

        # the following are added for logs to debug tests that somehow fail
        def _get_connectors_to_query_list(self, *args, **kwargs):
            connectors_to_query = super()._get_connectors_to_query_list(*args, **kwargs)
            self.logger.info("Connectors to query: %s", connectors_to_query)
            return connectors_to_query

        def _extract_select_account(self, args):
            connector_accounts_config = super()._extract_select_account(args)
            self.logger.info("Connector accounts config: %s", connector_accounts_config)
            return connector_accounts_config

    with patch("base.baseConnector.BaseConnector.field_dict", return_value={}):
        conn = AllConnectorCountingConnectors()

    expected_connectors = (
        set(connectors.__all__) - set(["all"]) - conn.CONNECTORS_TO_SKIP
    )

    conn.conn_called_connectors = set()

    conn.get_data(fields=None)

    assert (
        set(conn.conn_called_connectors) == expected_connectors
    ), "The default queried connectors list is not as expected"

    # Include googlesheets
    conn.conn_called_connectors = set()
    conn.get_data(fields=None, include_connectors="facebook,googlesheets")

    assert set(conn.conn_called_connectors) == expected_connectors | {
        "googlesheets"
    }, "Including non-default connectors did not work correctly"

    # Exclude some connectors
    conn.conn_called_connectors = set()
    conn.get_data(fields=None, exclude_connectors="facebook,googleanalytics")

    assert set(conn.conn_called_connectors) == expected_connectors - {
        "facebook",
        "googleanalytics",
    }, "Excluding some connectors did not work correctly"


def test_all_connector_returns_fields_from_all_the_connectors():
    """Test that the /all connector field list combines all the other lists."""
    conn = AllConnector()
    all_fields = conn.field_list
    all_field_ids = [f["id"] for f in all_fields]

    assert len(all_field_ids) == len(
        set(all_field_ids)
    ), "Field ids in /all are not unique"

    for connector_name, connector_fields in field_lists.items():
        for f in connector_fields:
            assert (
                f["id"] in all_field_ids
            ), f"Field {f['id']} exists in {connector_name} but not in /all"


def test_fields_include_datasource():
    """The "datasource" field should be included even if no connector have it."""
    # Build /all with only one mock list of fields that never contain "datasource"
    connector = AllConnector()
    connector._list_existing_connectors = lambda: ["connector1"]  # type: ignore

    # pylint: disable=too-few-public-methods
    class ConnectorWithHardcodedFields:
        @property
        def field_list(self):
            return [{"id": "field1"}]

    def get_with_hardcoded_fields(connector_name):  # pylint: disable=unused-argument
        return ConnectorWithHardcodedFields()

    connector._get_single_connector = get_with_hardcoded_fields  # type: ignore

    all_fields = connector.field_list
    all_field_ids = [f["id"] for f in all_fields]

    assert "datasource" in all_field_ids


@pytest.mark.timeout(120)
def test_all_connector_gets_expected_data_from_the_api(
    request_data_fixture,
):  # pylint: disable=redefined-outer-name
    """Test a basic request from the /all connector."""
    # time how much it takes to execute this request
    response, params = request_data_fixture

    assert (
        response.status_code == 200
    ), "Query returned unexpected error status code. Response: " + str(
        response.get_data()
    )

    res = response.get_json()
    assert "error" not in res
    assert "data" in res

    if "messages" in res:
        print(f"/all connector returned messages: {res['messages']}")

    data = res["data"]

    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    connectors_without_date = [
        "zoho",
        "klaviyo",
        "hubspot",  # TODO: is hubspot supposed to work with dates?
        "sendinblue",
    ]

    for conn in connectors_without_date:
        index_names = df[df["source"] == conn].index
        df.drop(index_names, inplace=True)

    if "date_from" in params and "date_to" in params:
        df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"]).dt.date

        assert not any(pd.isnull(df["date"])), "some dates could not be parsed"
        assert isinstance(params["date_from"], str)  # for mypy type checking
        assert isinstance(params["date_to"], str)  # for mypy type checking
        data_outside_requested_dates = df[
            (
                df["date"]
                < datetime.datetime.strptime(params["date_from"], "%Y-%m-%d").date()
            )
            | (
                df["date"]
                > datetime.datetime.strptime(params["date_to"], "%Y-%m-%d").date()
            )
        ]
        print("sadasdas", data_outside_requested_dates.to_string())
        assert (
            len(data_outside_requested_dates) == 0
        ), f"from_date and to_date are not respected: {data_outside_requested_dates}"
    assert isinstance(params["fields"], str)  # mypy type check
    expected_columns = params["fields"].split(",")
    expected_columns = [field.lower().replace(" ", "_") for field in expected_columns]

    assert set(expected_columns) == set(
        df.columns
    ), "Returned columns don't match the request"

    # Test sum of costs
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df = df.replace("", np.nan)
    df["clicks"] = df["clicks"].astype(float)
    df["spend"] = df["spend"].astype(float)
    df["sessions"] = df["sessions"].astype(float)

    # Test sum of costs per source
    df = df.groupby(["source"]).sum()

    df = df.loc[(df.spend > 0) | (df.clicks > 0) | (df.sessions > 10)]
    df = df[["clicks", "spend", "sessions"]]

    df_exp = pd.DataFrame(
        [
            {"source": "(direct)", "clicks": 0.0, "spend": 0.0, "sessions": 347.0},
            # removing for now
            # TODO enable later
            # {
            #     "source": "apple_search_ads",
            #     "clicks": 29.0,
            #     "spend": 44.5376,
            #     "sessions": 0.0,
            # },
            {"source": "awin", "clicks": 211.0, "spend": 0.310000, "sessions": 0.0},
            {
                "source": "bing",
                "clicks": 2981.0,
                "spend": 550.120000,
                "sessions": 9.0,
            },
            {
                "source": "cm360",
                "clicks": 7.0,
                "spend": 0.0,
                "sessions": 0.0,
            },
            {
                "source": "criteo",
                "clicks": 6237.0,
                "spend": 2008.048,
                "sessions": 0.0,
            },
            {
                "source": "datastudio.google.com",
                "clicks": 0.0,
                "spend": 0.0,
                "sessions": 144.0,
            },
            {
                "source": "dv360",
                "clicks": 177.0,
                "spend": 380,
                "sessions": 0.0,
            },
            {
                "source": "facebook",
                "clicks": 8.0,
                "spend": 9.85,
                "sessions": 0.0,
            },
            {
                "source": "facebook_organic",
                "clicks": 43.0,
                "spend": 0.0,
                "sessions": 0.0,
            },
            {
                "source": "google",
                "clicks": 25.0,
                "spend": 5.83,
                "sessions": 677.0,
            },
            {
                "source": "googleanalytics4",
                "clicks": 0.0,
                "spend": 0.0,
                "sessions": 77.0,
            },
            # {"source": "idealo", "clicks": 3924.0, "spend": 0.0, "sessions": 0.0},
            {"source": "instagram", "clicks": 31.0, "spend": 0.0, "sessions": 0.0},
            {"source": "linkedin", "clicks": 1.0, "spend": 3.660000, "sessions": 1.0},
            {
                "source": "pinterest",
                "clicks": 360.0,
                "spend": 203.752767,
                "sessions": 0.0,
            },
            {
                "source": "quora",
                "clicks": 52.0,
                "spend": 44.680000,
                "sessions": 0.0,
            },
            {"source": "rtbhouse", "clicks": 23858.0, "spend": 0.0, "sessions": 0.0},
            {
                "source": "searchconsole",
                "clicks": 519.0,
                "spend": 0.0,
                "sessions": 0.0,
            },
            {
                "source": "snapchat",
                "clicks": 0.0,
                "spend": 755.466231,
                "sessions": 0.0,
            },
            # {
            #     "source": "tiktok",
            #     "clicks": 1229.0,
            #     "spend": 330.820000,
            #     "sessions": 0.0,
            # },
            {
                "source": "twitter",
                "clicks": 819.0,
                "spend": 367.56050799999997,
                "sessions": 0.0,
            },
            {
                "source": "adform",
                "clicks": 13072.0,
                "spend": 0.0,
                "sessions": 0.0,
            },
            {
                "source": "google_ad_manager",
                "clicks": 4078.0,
                "spend": 2833905000.0,
                "sessions": 0.0,
            },
            {
                "source": "rakuten_advertising",
                "clicks": 12840.0,
                "spend": 0.0,
                "sessions": 0.0,
            },
        ]
    ).set_index("source")

    df.sort_index(inplace=True)
    df_exp.sort_index(inplace=True)
    print(df)
    print(df_exp)
    assert (
        df.index.to_list() == df_exp.index.to_list()
    ), f"Sources in the data are not as expected, {res.get('messages')}"

    # Values in data frames are considered equal if their difference is <= 10%.
    # If some values are fluctating to a greater extent then probably they
    # should be excluded from the test.
    pd.testing.assert_frame_equal(df, df_exp, rtol=0.10)


@pytest.mark.timeout(120)
def test_unsupported_fields_are_filtered_out(
    request_data_fixture,
):  # pylint: disable=redefined-outer-name
    """Check that only supported fields are queried for each connector.

    Check whether the all connector updates the list of fields to be pulled
    for each specific connector to exclude fields that are not present in
    specific-connector's field list.
    """
    res, params = request_data_fixture

    assert res.status_code == 200, (
        "Query returned unexpected error status code. Response: " + res.text
    )

    res_json = res.get_json()
    assert "error" not in res_json
    assert "data" in res_json
    assert "messages" in res_json

    # Test that messages (about errors from specific connectors) are as expected.
    # The idea here is to check that messages come only from connectors that
    # do not have field lists. If none of the requested fields is not present
    # in a field list for a specific connector then the `all` connector is
    # expected to skip pulling data from that connector. As a result, error
    # messages from such connectors (such as 'the field is not supported')
    # cannot appear in the data returned from the `all` connector.
    actual_messages = res_json["messages"]

    assert isinstance(actual_messages, list)
    assert all(isinstance(m, Mapping) for m in actual_messages)

    assert actual_messages == [], f"Messages are not as empty: {actual_messages}"

    # Check returned data
    # get only the datasources needed for this test
    datasources = [
        {
            "datasource": "googleanalytics",
            "newusers": 699.0,
            "order_current_total_price": 0.0,
        },
        {
            "datasource": "googleanalytics4",
            "newusers": 55.0,
            "order_current_total_price": 0.0,
        },
        {
            "datasource": "shopify",
            "newusers": 0.0,
            "order_current_total_price": 1706.79,
        },
        # {"datasource": "tiktok", "newusers": 0.0,
        # "order_current_total_price": 0.0},
    ]
    data = []
    for obj in res_json["data"]:
        if obj["datasource"] in [d["datasource"] for d in datasources]:
            data.append(obj)

    df = pd.DataFrame(data)

    # Test that columns are as expected
    assert set(params["fields"].split(",")) == set(
        df.columns
    ), "Returned columns don't match the request"

    # Test that the number of rows is as expected
    actual_rows = df.shape[0]

    expected_rows = 100
    assert actual_rows == expected_rows, (
        "Number of rows is not as expected. "
        f"Actual: {actual_rows}, expected: {expected_rows}"
    )

    # Test that metric sums are as expected
    df = df.replace("", np.nan)
    df["newusers"] = df["newusers"].astype(float)
    df["order_current_total_price"] = df["order_current_total_price"].astype(float)

    actual_sums = np.round(df[["newusers", "order_current_total_price"]].sum(), 1)
    actual_sums = actual_sums.to_dict()

    expected_sums = {"newusers": 812.0, "order_current_total_price": 1706.8}

    sums_are_as_expected = len(actual_sums) == len(expected_sums) and all(
        v == pytest.approx(actual_sums[k]) for k, v in expected_sums.items()
    )
    assert sums_are_as_expected, (
        "Metric sums are not as expected. "
        f"Actual: {actual_sums}, expected: {expected_sums}"
    )

    # Test sums by main sources
    # sources with small number of `newusers` are filtered out to reduce
    # the size of the data frame with expected data
    df = df[df["newusers"].isna() | (df["newusers"] > 10)]
    df = df.groupby(["datasource"]).sum()
    df = df[["newusers", "order_current_total_price"]].sort_index()
    df = df.reset_index()

    expected_sums_by_group = pd.DataFrame(datasources)

    # data frames are printed to test output only if the test fails below
    print(df)
    print(expected_sums_by_group)

    # Values in data frames are considered equal if their difference is <= 1%.
    pd.testing.assert_frame_equal(df, expected_sums_by_group, rtol=0.01)


def test_no_fields_requested_returns_error():
    """Test that an error is returned when no field is requested."""
    connector = "all"
    finalurl = f"http://localhost:5001/{connector}"
    params = {
        "fields": "",
        "date_from": "2021-06-08",
        "date_to": "2021-06-09",
        "api_key": "2ee6af7ff92f753363d420fc4a2b1233f136",
    }

    try:
        res = requests.get(url=finalurl, params=params, timeout=120)
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as exc:
        print("ERROR: Response not as expected, if needed restart docker instance with")
        print("docker-compose up --force-recreate -d connectors")
        raise exc

    assert res.status_code == requests.codes["bad_request"], (
        "Query returned unexpected error status code. Response: " + res.text
    )

    data = res.json()
    assert "error" in data, "Expected error key if no field queried"
    assert "data" not in data, "Unexpected data with no field queried"
    assert "messages" not in data, "Unexpected messages with no field queried"

    assert (
        data["error"] == "Missing required parameter: fields"
    ), "Unexpected error message"


def test_all_field_list_contains_fields_for_configured_connectors():
    """Test that the /all field list only includes fields for configured connectors."""
    all_connectors = ["a", "b", "c"]
    user_configured_connectors = ["a", "c"]

    # The datasource field is always added
    datasource_field = {
        "available_in_connectors": [],
        "description": "The name of the Windsor connector returning the row",
        "id": "datasource",
        "name": "Data Source",
        "type": "TEXT",
    }

    class MockConnector:  # pylint: disable=too-few-public-methods
        def __init__(self, name):
            self.name = name

        @property
        def field_list(self):
            return [{"id": f"field_from_{self.name}"}]

    conn = AllConnector()

    conn._get_connectors_with_db_config = (
        lambda *args, **kwargs: user_configured_connectors
    )
    conn._list_existing_connectors = lambda *args, **kwargs: all_connectors  # type: ignore # pylint: disable=line-too-long
    conn._get_single_connector = MockConnector  # type: ignore

    # No user was setup in conn, so all fields should be returned
    assert conn.field_list == [
        {"id": "field_from_a", "available_in_connectors": ["a"]},
        {"id": "field_from_b", "available_in_connectors": ["b"]},
        {"id": "field_from_c", "available_in_connectors": ["c"]},
        datasource_field,
    ]

    # Specifying a user, only the fields for configured connectors are returned
    conn.user_name = "connectortest"
    assert conn.field_list == [
        {"id": "field_from_a", "available_in_connectors": ["a"]},
        {"id": "field_from_c", "available_in_connectors": ["c"]},
        datasource_field,
    ]


def test_all_connector_with_select_accounts(monkeypatch):
    """Test all connectors select_accounts option."""
    conn = AllConnector()
    conn._get_connectors_with_db_config = connectors.__all__.copy

    _get_data_for_one_connector = MagicMock(conn._get_data_for_one_connector)
    _get_data_for_one_connector.return_value = ([], None)
    monkeypatch.setattr(
        conn, "_get_data_for_one_connector", _get_data_for_one_connector
    )

    conn.get_data(fields="spend", select_accounts="facebook__2,facebook__aa")
    connector_calls = {
        c.args[0]: c.args[1]["select_accounts"]
        for c in _get_data_for_one_connector.call_args_list
    }
    assert connector_calls == {"facebook": "2,aa"}, "invalid fb select_accounts args"

    with pytest.raises(UserHandledException):
        conn.get_data(fields="", select_accounts="invalid")
    with pytest.raises(UserHandledException):
        conn.get_data(fields="", select_accounts="facebook_a")


@pytest.mark.timeout(120)
def test_all_reddit_amzn_sp(client):
    """Test that all connector gets data from reddit and amazon_sp.

    Since reddit only keeps data for up to 6 months,
    this test will need to be updated appropriately.
    """
    params: dict = {
        "fields": "campaign,clicks,spend,impressions,date,account_id,"
        "source,amazon_fulfilled_shipments_data_general__merchant_order_item_id,"
        "amazon_fulfilled_shipments_data_general__purchase_date",
        "date_from": "2022-09-27",
        "date_to": "2022-09-27",
        "api_key": "2ee6af7ff92f753363d420fc4a2b1233f136",
        "force_refresh": True,
        # only querying relevant ones for the sake of performance
        "select_accounts": "select_accounts=amazon_sp__Pivo-US,"
        "amazon_sp__Pivo-US,reddit__f7aiz9kz",
    }

    response = client.get(path="/all", query_string=params)

    assert (
        response.status_code == 200
    ), "Query returned unexpected error status code. Response: " + str(
        response.get_data()
    )

    res = response.get_json()
    assert "error" not in res
    assert "data" in res

    df = pd.DataFrame(res["data"])
    assert "reddit" in set(df["source"]), "all connector returned no reddit data."
    assert "amazon_sp" in set(df["source"]), "all connector returned no amazon_sp data."

    data_outside_requested_dates = df[
        (df["date"] < params["date_from"]) | (df["date"] > params["date_to"])
    ]
    assert (
        len(data_outside_requested_dates) == 0
    ), f"from_date and to_date are not respected: {data_outside_requested_dates}"
```

`-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root 21494 Feb 10 17:10 test_all_connector.py`

While trying to run image with permissions like `docker run --user 1000:1000 connectors_connectors_1` i have the error

```
 * Tip: There are .env or .flaskenv files present. Do "pip install python-dotenv" to use them.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/connectors/.local/bin/flask", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/connectors/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 988, in main
    cli.main()
  File "/home/connectors/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 579, in main
    return super().main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/connectors/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1053, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/connectors/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1653, in invoke
    cmd_name, cmd, args = self.resolve_command(ctx, args)
  File "/home/connectors/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1700, in resolve_command
    cmd = self.get_command(ctx, cmd_name)
  File "/home/connectors/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 535, in get_command
    return info.load_app().cli.get_command(ctx, name)
  File "/home/connectors/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 389, in load_app
    app = locate_app(import_name, name)
  File "/home/connectors/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 234, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "/app/api/app.py", line 15, in <module>
    from api.fields import fields_blueprint
  File "/app/api/fields.py", line 13, in <module>
    from api.oauth import validate_auth_if_provided
  File "/app/api/oauth.py", line 13, in <module>
    from base import api_helpers, env
  File "/app/base/api_helpers.py", line 11, in <module>
    from base import env
  File "/app/base/env.py", line 32, in <module>
    SECRETS_PATH: str = os.environ["SECRETS_PATH"]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/os.py", line 679, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'SECRETS_PATH'

Error: '' is not a valid port number.
```